# In three.js how to make light on sphere sharp?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have simple three.js scene with sphere and directional light. On the sphere you can see that it get gradually darker. How to make the transition from light to dark faster. How to make light "sharper"?

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 3;
camera.position.z = 6;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x777777
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve the intended affect is via toon shading. Hence, give [MeshToonMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshToonMaterial) a try. You can also defined a [gradientMap](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshToonMaterial.gradientMap) that defines the distinct lit areas of the material.

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 3;
camera.position.z = 6;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
  color: 0x777777
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `material.shininess`.  [See this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-materials.html)

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.z = 2;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x777777,
  shininess: 400,
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js"></script>
```

Even with a `MeshToonMaterial` you need to set `shininess` to 0 if you want no specular highlights

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.z = 2;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
  color: 0x777777,
  shininess: 0,

});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

further, the relative amount of light is hard coded unless you use a `gradientMap`

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.z = 2;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
  color: 'red',
  shininess: 0,
  gradientMap: new THREE.DataTexture(
    new Uint8Array([
        0,   // black (color away from light multiplied by color of material)
      255,   // white (color toward light multiplied by material
    ]),
    2, // width of texture
    1, // height of texture,
    THREE.LuminanceFormat,  // format of texture
  ),
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(50, 50, 30);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

Note the gradientMap above is a 2x1 pixel texture so the cutoff will be 50% between facing the light and not facing the light. To move the cutoff make the gradientMap bigger. For example a 5x1 pixel texture with `black, black, white, white, white` will be 40% black, 60% white

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.z = 2;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
  color: 'red',
  shininess: 0,
  gradientMap: new THREE.DataTexture(
    new Uint8Array([
        0,   // black (color away from light multiplied by color of material)
        0,
      255,   // white (color toward light multiplied by material
      255, 
      255,
    ]),
    5, // width of texture
    1, // height of texture,
    THREE.LuminanceFormat,  // format of texture
  ),
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(50, 50, 30);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

If you want to set the 2 colors explicitly then make the `gradientMap` have the colors and set the material color to white

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls, sphere, geometry, material, light;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.z = 2;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
  color: 'white',
  shininess: 0,
  gradientMap: new THREE.DataTexture(
    new Uint8Array([
        255, 0, 255,   // purple (color away from light multiplied by color of material)
        0, 255, 255,   // cyan (color toward light multiplied by material
    ]),
    2, // width of texture
    1, // height of texture,
    THREE.RGBFormat,  // format of texture
  ),
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(50, 50, 30);
scene.add(light);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

If you want more than 2 colors/divisions then put more than 2 colors in the gradientMap

Comment: I don't want specular reflections, I want sphere to be divided on two halves, one lit and one unlit.

Comment: Mugen87's answer covers that, So does the link in my answer. Note if you just want two colors you need to use `MeshToonMaterial`, set `material.shininess` to 0, , and you need to provide a `gradientMap` if you want to be able to set the colors and/or positions of the cutoff